# PHP Encoder and Accelerator

Tags: php, encoder, accelerator

I'm looking for recommendations for PHP encoders and accelerators.

From what I can tell, APC is the de facto standard for accelerators: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php. As for encoders, I'm still not sure what to consider. Suggestions?

By the way, the encoder is needed to protect some intellectual property. So if there are other solutions, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: "So if there are other solutions, I'm open to ideas." Sure - contract law.

Comment: Doesn't work well if you are hosting your code in another country -- and you are potentially trying to hide the code from the host.

Comment: Might I suggest getting a web host you don't feel you have to hide from? There are plenty of reputable ones around. Amazon's not going to risk losing all their EC2 customers over your IP. You're trying to deal with what is fundamentally a non-technical problem with a technical solution.

Comment: EC2 was not something I considered. Might be a good solution. What about accelerators?

Comment: As you said, APC is the de facto standard. It's a free, easy first step when you start needing to scale out.

Comment: I've never used an accelerator. So, even though I have read it is the de facto standard, I still want input from those who have used it and similar products.

Comment: Have you seen this list on WP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators ? 
It contains quite some information about which projects are dead and which are alive and kicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular PHP encoders I've seen have been Zendguard and Ioncube. Neither of them are particularly amazing, but they're what there is.

Between the two of them, Ioncube has the small advantage of being compatible between PHP 5.2 and 5.3. (Zendguard requires that you encode separate files for the two, which is kind of nasty.)